# arraylist: comparing an object with a string

Tags: java, string, object, arraylist

Hi guys could anyone tell me where im going wrong?

The basic aim of this class is to define a favourite items arraylist which in this case is about cars. The cars objects have a car name and a rating for car 1-5.

how do you see if a string is equal to the car objects rating. 
im messing up the part where you compare a string or int to an car object in array list. what is wrong with my equals() method? can contains() method work the same way?

The numberOfItemsOfRating method allows user to specify rating and hence the method returns the no cars with the rating. the searchForItems method checks if String description specified matches the cars name in array list, and hence returns the car in arraylist.

here is a glimpse of my two methods with constructors and variables:

```
public class FavouriteItems
{
    private ArrayList<Item> cars; 

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class FavouriteItems
     */
    public FavouriteItems()
    {
        cars= new ArrayList<Item>();

    }

    /**
     * Add a new Item to your collection
     * @param newItem The Item object to be added to the collection.
     */
    public void addToFavourites(Item newItem) 
    {
        cars.add(newItem);

    }
    /**
     * Count the number of Items with a given rating 
     * @return The number of Items (Item objects) 
     *          whose rating is rating (could be 0).
     *          If the rating parameter is outside the valid
     *          range 1..5 then print an error message and return 0.
     */
    public int numberOfItemsOfRating(int rating)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        if(rating >= 1 && rating <=5) 
        {
            for ( int i =0; i < cars.size(); i++)
            {
                int num = rating;
                String al = Integer.toString(rating);
                if(cars.get(i).equals(al))
                {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("No cars match your ratings");
            counter = 0;
        }
        return counter;
    }

    /**
     * Find the details of a Item given its description
     * @return Item object if its description is in the collection
     * or null if there is no item with that description
     */
    public Item searchForItem(String description) 
    {
         for(int i=0; i<cars.size(); i++)
        { 
            if(cars.equals(description))
            { 
                 return cars.get(i);
            } 
            else 
            { 
                return null;
            }
        }  
      }
}
```

Comment: implement equals() method for Car

Comment: that is what i tried doing but it doesnt seem to work

Comment: You are comparing an Item object to an Integer - is this what you intended?

Comment: yes that's what it want's us to do, does equals() work on objects?

Comment: What do you store in the `Item`-class?

Comment: you store (car names, rating)

Comment: this would basically be a demo                      myfavourites.addToFavourites(new Item("Audi", 5));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the way you should use the equals method, instead I suggest you use or implement `Item#getRating()` and `Item#getDescription()`. Use `cars.get(i).getDescription().equals(description)` to check for the description. To check for the rating use `cars.get(i).getRating() == rating`.

You should not use equals to compare an Item with a string, as this would violate the equals [contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29).

Comment: it's not making a difference. I understand how your calling each specific item in arraylist, not adding get(i) was my mistake. thanks

Comment: You should not use the equals method of Car to check for a rating or description of the Car. Instead use the getRating/getDesription methods of the Car and then use == to check for the rating and use equals to check for the description.

Comment: thanks for the rating i used if(cars.get(i).getRating()== rating) and it worked, lets see if the equals method works for searchitems:DX

Comment: thanks this is what i did to the description method and it worked you might like to see it :  public Item searchForItem(String description) 
    {
       int counter = 0;
       Item des = null;
         for(int i=0; i<cars.size(); i++)
        { 
            
            if(cars.get(i).getDescription().equals(description))
            { 
                
                 des = cars.get(i);
            } 
            
             
            
            
        }  
        return des;
        
        
    }

Comment: I'm glad, I could help. Still there seems to be an issue. What do you exactly want to return? At the moment it seems you return the last Item in the list that matches the given description. If you want to return the first item found, you can change `des = cars.get(i);` to `return cars.get(i)` and change `return des;` to `return null`.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing your equality check based off the object itself, when instead you should be doing it against *properties of the object*. In your particular case you should be looking at the `rating` attribute of each Car/Item in your collection. Your code would look something like this:

```
final String ratingStr = Integer.toString(rating);

int counter = 0;
for (for final Item car: cars) {
    if(ratingStr.equals(car.getRating()) {
        ++counter;
}

System.out.println("Number of 'cars' with the rating is: " + counter);
```

Two quick comments, you ***should*** implement equality methods for your `Item` class. But in this case that is not the actual source of your issues. Also, you mention cars alot in your code, but your bean class is called 'Item'. You might want to reconcile that as it is potentially confusing to others who read your code.

Don't forget to fix your `searchForItem` method as well, currently you are testing equality of an array list to a string, which will never return true. Correct it in the same way as described above, but using the `description` attribute of your car, instead of the `rating` attribute.

Comment: What doesn't seem to work? Have you defined methods on your `Item` class to get/set both the `rating` and `description`?

Answer (score 0):

```
cars.get(i)
```

returns an Item, not a String. So

```
if(cars.get(i).equals(al))
```

is not correct.

Comment: sorry, answer with an iPad is not simple, above all when I'm not english :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(cars.equals(description))
```

Your ArrayList `cars` (the whole list in this case) will never equal a single String.

If you want to search for a car, you'll need to check all items in your list and see, if their name (or whatever information you store in the `Item`-class) matches the given `description`.

Comment: yeah isn't that what im trying to do? and yes i think it should be if(cars.get(i).equals(description)) would that work?

Comment: That depends on how you implemented the `equals`-method for the `Item`-class. If you didn't explicitly implement it, this will not work.

Answer (score 0):

`if(cars.get(i).equals(al))` 
**Here you are compare the string with object so it's wrong**
incase of use that u can try the below coding

```
if(cars.get(i).getItem().equals(al))
```

is possible where getItem() one of the variable in cars Class named "item", type as 'string' and put it getter and setter.

**lly  if(cars.equals(description)) is wrong. here u are trying to compare the list name with string**
so better to use the below coding

```
 if(cars.get(i).getDescription().equals(description))
    return cars.get(i);
```

is possible where getDescription() one of the variable in cars Class named "description", type as 'string' and put it getter and setter.